# How to POST a Dictionary using @PartMap

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm sending a POST message using retrofit2 to upload a file plus a couple of parameters. Some of the parameters are Dictionaries. In order do this, I have the following:

```
@Multipart
@POST("incidents")
Call<MachineRequest> sendMachineRequest(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> partMap, @Part MultipartBody.Part image;
```

The problem is: It seems as if I can upload Strings as value for my parameters only. I utilize `RequestBody create(MediaType contentType, String content)` to create entries for the @PartMap Map. Of course, the Dictionaries have to be strings to fit in the RequestBody. But this leads to a wrong interpretation in the Rails backend. The values are interpreted as String and not as Dictionary.

`"incident"=>"{\"type\":\"MachineRequest\"}"`

instead of

`"incident"=>{\"type\":\"MachineRequest\"}`

So my question is: How can I add a Dictionary in @PartMap, or how can I create a ReqeustBody that holds a Dictionary?

Comment: A comment for the downvote would be nice. How else could I possibly improve my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though my question was downvoted, I still believe my findings can be helpful to anyone who is new to retrofit and tries to POST a file along with a more complex Java object.

So my `@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> partMap` contains mostly keys of String with one value of String. I further added a key of String with a value of HashMap.

```
Map<String,RequestBody> mrm = new HashMap<String, RequestBody>();

HashMap<String,String> incident = new HashMap<String, String>();
incident.put("type","MachineRequest");

RequestBody incident = createPartFromString(String.valueOf(incident);
RequestBody machine = createPartFromString(String.valueOf(getMachine()));
mrm.put("incident",incident);
mrm.put("machine",machine);
```

This ended up in my rails backend as `"incident"=>"{\"type\":\"MachineRequest\"}"`. The value of `incident` got interpreted as a string instead of a dictionary -> 
`NoMethodError - undefined method permit for "{'type':'MachineRequest'}":String:`

In order to get this fixed it changed my code as follows:

```
Map<String,RequestBody> mrm = new HashMap<String, RequestBody>();

RequestBody incident = createPartFromString("MachineRequest");
RequestBody machine = createPartFromString(String.valueOf(getMachine()));
mrm.put("incident[type]",incident);
mrm.put("machine",machine);
```

Which made it arrive like expected: `"incident"=>{"type"=>"MachineRequest"}` and made Rails finally able to get hold of the value of `type`.

In the end, `mrm.put("incident[type]",incident);` made the whole difference. At least with a `@Multipart` POST requests. For non `@Mutipart` messages, the former code works fine too.

It took me quite a while sort this out as I haven't found an example or documentation for this scenario anywhere. So hopefully this helps people facing the same problem I had, or at least helping them to narrow down other problems.